# How does $E[X]+E[X(X-1)]-(E[X])^2=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$

Tags: probability, statistics

There's probably some properties of expectation I'm not familiar with that makes this true. If someone could explain it to me that'd be great. What does E[X(X-1)] equate to?

Comment: There might be a wrong sign in your equation. Are you sure it is correct?

Answer (score 1):

$$\Bbb{E}[X(X-1)]=\Bbb{E}[X^2-X]$$
Now use $\displaystyle \color{red}{\text{Linearity of Expectation}}$  to get the answer as $$\Bbb{E}[X(X-1)]=\Bbb{E}[X^2]-\Bbb{E}[X]$$

Answer (score 0):

Because $$\mathbb E[X(X-1)]=\mathbb E[X^2]-\mathbb E[X].$$